# How to make a batch file sleep for some time inside an if statement?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write the below code, and I want it to display the error before it exits, but whenever I run it, it exits right away.

```
@echo off
cd "haha"
if %errorlevel% 1 (
   echo Failure reason given is %errorlevel%
   sleep 5
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
echo files deleted successfully!
del /Q *
pause
```

I have also tried `timeout /t 5` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: Use either `If ErrorLevel 1` or `If %ErrorLevel%==1`

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: @Compo I tried both but unfortunately it is still exiting right away, i can tell it is entering the if statement because it is not pausing, otherwise it would pause

Comment: There is no `sleep` command in Windows natively! `timeout /T 5` actually waits for 4 up to 5 seconds. To really wait for 5 seconds, use ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul` (6 attempts to ping local host, hence 5 times pause; suppress output by `> nul`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
@echo off
cd "haha" 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
   echo Failure reason given is %errorlevel%
   timeout /t 5
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, THANKS! one more thing, how can i print the error? i mean it is obviously that the directory doesn't exist, is there anyway to print the error as to why it has exited? thanks alot!

Comment: remove the `2>nul` and please put the question as answered

Comment: Thanks a ton! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
if errorlevel 1 (
```

meaning `if errorlevel is 1 or greater`

OR

```
if %errorlevel% geq 1 (
```

which means the same thing.

As it stands, `cmd` is interpreting you code as

`if 1 1 (`

(assuming `errorlevel` is 1). This is a syntax error, so `cmd` shows a message. If you are running by point-click and giggle, the window will close. If you are running from the prompt, then `cmd` will report a syntax error.

Be warned however that executing an `exit` statement from the prompt will abort the `cmd` instance. Better to use `goto :eof` unless you have good reason otherwise.

`timeout /t 5` should work, but will generate a countdown.

`timeout /t 5 >nul` should appear simply to wait. The issue is that you have to solve the `if` syntax first, else the `timeout` instruction won't be reached.